# Paradox curve lengths limit

Tags: geometry, analysis, pi, fake-proofs

A possible similarity [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4)

Consider a sequence of curves as follow:

$C_1$ is a semicircle drawn on the segment $[0,1]$, as in figure bellow; $C_2$ is the union of semicirocles of diameters $[0,1/2], [1/2,1]$; \, $C_3$ is the union of semicircles of diameters $[0,1/4],[1/4,1/2],[1/2,3/4],[3/4,1]$ etc....

Obviously, this sequences of curves tend to a limit, which is the segment $[0,1]$.

Moreover, the lengths of this curves are
\begin{align*}
l(C_1)& = \frac{\pi}{2}  \\
l(C_2)& = 2\times \frac{\pi}{4} =\frac{\pi}{2}\\
l(C_3)& = 4\times \frac{\pi}{8} =\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\end{align*}
So the sequence does not tend to $l([0,1])=1$.

How do you explain this bizarreness?

Any help is welcome and thank's in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is bizarre about it?

Comment: The fact that $\pi=2$

Comment: The link you gave specifically gives an explanation, namely that the length function is not continuous. That is, the length of a limit of curves is not the limit of the lengths of the curves. For some information about the history of this result, see [What is the history of staircase or =4 paradox?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/11240/264)